# Styled-components and react-icons <IconContext.Provider> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-icons

i'm new to styled-components and i want to use <IconContext.Provider> from react icons this is my react component:

```
<myComp>
 <AiFillPlusCircle />
</myComp>
```

and this is my styled components code:

```
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
    
export const myComp= styled(IconContext.Provider)`
 color: rgb(71, 71, 71) !important;
 vertical-align: middle !important;
 font-size: 1.7rem !important;
`;
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrap some component with `styled` hoc, it just passes `className` prop to your component.

`IconContext.Provider` expects only `value` prop. This prop is object and can [contain](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#configuration) `style`, `attr` or `className` values. You can just pass `style` attribute to configure it like this:

```
const MyProvider = ({children}) => <IconContext.Provider value={{ style: { someStyle: someValue } }}>{children}</IconContext.Provider>;
```

However, if you would like to use styled-components, it could be possible like this:

```
const MyProvider = ({className, children}) => <IconContext.Provider value={{className}}>{children}</IconContext.Provider>;

const MyProviderStyled = styled(MyProvider)`
  some-style: some-value;
`;
```